# Is there a native log for outgoing ssh commands?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh, security

On a Ubuntu 16.04 server, I got a warning from my ISP that my IP had been used to attack other hosts, with the following attached :

```
May 23 22:42:07 shared02 sshd[23972]: Invalid user ircd from <my-ip>
May 23 22:42:07 shared02 sshd[23972]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<my-ip>
May 23 22:42:09 shared02 sshd[23972]: Failed password for invalid user ircd from <my-ip> port 54952 ssh2
May 23 22:42:09 shared02 sshd[23972]: Received disconnect from <my-ip> port 54952:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
May 23 22:42:09 shared02 sshd[23972]: Disconnected from <my-ip> port 54952 [preauth]
```

I checked the log at /var/log/auth.log and found out a dictionary attack had been going on for at least 10 days on my own server, and that at some point a weak user password got cracked.

I assume the attacking bot used this access to attack other targets, which is why I got the previous warning. However I don't know where this activity could have been logged. Is there any file that contains this information natively in Ubuntu systems ?

Also, as bonus question, I noticed the bot tried to log as root from this user, but as far as I can tell it did not try to sudo any command, why would it not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no, there are no logs about outgoing events as it's assumed someone requested them.

Depending on how your attacker logged in and how they ran their attack, there may be entries in various history files (e.g. `~/.bash_history`), but there won't be anything in syslogs unless you specifically add rules to log that. If you want, you can [set up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30046/logging-outgoing-connections-as-they-happen/30099) outgoing connection logging, though some care must be taken to only log what you want to do. One such example is available [on the Fedora forum](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-163176.html) and leverages `iptables`.

As for your root login question. Generally, the attackers don't care much about getting root access. They only want another server to run their attack scripts on. `root` is part of the dictionary used for user attacks, just in the rare event that someone has a root account enabled with a weak password. Additionally, there's no guarantee that a user is in `/etc/sudoers`, and you're wasting precious attack time trying to see if a user has (unnecessary) `sudo` access.